# I'm using 2x12 for steps. At 4 feet, do I need a center support?

Tags: wood, load-bearing, pressure-treated

I'm using 2x12 for steps.   At 4 feet, do I need a center support?

Comment: Do you mean a stringer?  4 feet *wide*?

Comment: Open type steps or steps with risers?   Open type, a centre support/stringer will be helpful.

Answer (score 7):

2009 IRC and just about everything else in the US specifies 18” on center spacing for stringers with 2xwhatever treads.

So yes, you need at least a center stringer; maybe 2 if your treads overhang the outside stringers normally.

(As a total aside, a single 2x12 is prone to cupping and irregularity way more than two 2x6s, or that 2x12 ripped in half.)